# Use Higher Version of Unzip in Oracle EBS

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, oracle-application-server

-I encounter error during installing ORACLE EBS on LINUX 64 bit server.

-Log shows that:

```
RC-20200: Fatal: Could not find Unzip. At this time only Native UnZip 5.X is supported.
Please make sure you have UnZip 5.X in your path and try again...
Cannot execute Install for database ORACLE_HOME

RW-50010: Error: - script has returned an error:   1
RW-50004: Error code received when running external process.  Check log file for details.
Running Database Install Driver for PROD instance
```

-unzip version that currently in use is:

```
unzip -version

caution:  both -n and -o specified; ignoring -o
**UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009**, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.
```

So, do I need to downgrade my unzip version?

Any other rpm I missing before start installation?

Answer (score 0):

Per Doc 1410514.1 you could apply patch 9171651.
You will have to start the clone over from scratch.